# Sharepoint 2010 Foundation with .Net Framework 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, sharepoint-2010

I am having a Web Application with build target as .Net Framework 4.0.
I want to interact with the Sharepoint Object Model API's but it gives a framework 4.0 runtime does not supports Sharepoint.dll error.

Is their any tweak such that I can use Sharepoint 2010 with .Net Framework4.0.

Note: I cannnot change the build target of the web app to any other framework as I am using some exclusive features of .net 4.0 in my application.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry you probably will have no luck:

> There appears to be some confusion
>   around whether or not ASP.NET 4 is
>   supported for both MOSS and SharePoint
>   2010 - in short, the answer is that it
>   is not currently supported in either
>   product.
>
> Whilst it is possible to use ASP.NET
>   3.5 in MOSS by making some modifications to the SharePoint site
>   web.config (instructions for doing
>   that in MOSS here; SP2010 uses 3.5 by
>   default), this is unfortunately not
>   the case with version 4.
>
> The reason? ASP.NET 4 uses a new
>   version of the Common Language Runtime
>   (CLR). Whilst .NET 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5
>   all used version 2.0 of the CLR, .NET
>   4 uses version 4. I'm not entirely
>   sure what happened to version 3. There
>   is a decent post on stack overflow
>   with further details.

from [SharePoint 2010 and .NET 4: confused?](http://mossblogger.blogspot.com/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-and-net-4-confused.html)

Maybe .NET 4.0 Support will be added in a future update (SP1?) who knows...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, .Net 2.0 to 3.5 use a different application pool type from .Net 4.0; Mixing in the same app pool is not going to work.

What features of .Net 4.0 are you using, and perhaps the community can help you with a 3.5 solution?

Comment: I am using  edmx and i need referencial integrity in Model i.e the option for Including Foreign Key constraint in Model while adding edmx to my project App

Comment: Ouch -- that's going to be tricky. I'd recommend exposing the relevent parts of your Entity Framework domain as a WCF service or similar. The WCF contract version of your model should be workable on both 3.5 and 4.0.

Comment: Thats doesnt seem to be feasible solution as the edmx would be used between many modules and exposing it in such a way would not be possible.

Comment: Sorry to hear that -- but if you need both Sharepoint and .Net 4.0, it's going to involve some major work. Would probably be a good point at which to ensure that your domain model and persistence are nicely seperated. A few dozen calls in WCF would be quite simple at both ends.